# How to remove Floating Action Button from auto generated Scrolling Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I created a scrolling activity in Android Studio and I removed the code from the activity that sets the FAB's action, but there is not a matching attribute in the activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="myactivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_edit_address">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:text="@string/large_text" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Everything that I've found on Google says to remove the FAB XML attribute as well to stop it from showing up, but that seems outdated because it is not there. Where can I go to remove this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you generate a Scrolling Activity it will generate 2 xml files called `activity_scrolling.xml` and `content_scrolling.xml`. Just remove the FAB block from the `activity_scrolling.xml` file.

Delete this block:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Comment: Thank you, don't know how I missed that. Will accept as answer when allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Right click **layout** folder then click **Find in path**

Search **Floating**

Delete the block from there then **Ctrl + Enter**

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apyOM.png)